# PHP REST API Key and User Token Authentication

Tags: security, restful-authentication, api-key

I wanted to check with you guys if my API Key and user Authentication scheme makes sense or not. My server side code is in PHP and the Database is MySQL. This is the scheme I have in mind:
I am implementing a REST API in a backend server that will be called by a Mobile App (for now). At this point, I only want known Mobile Apps to connect to this API. So I am using a one-time API Key that has been given to the Mobile App during installation. Every request from the App passes the API Key that my API checks before going further. This Key is stored in a Database table. This completes my API Key checking and seems to allow only known Apps from calling my APIs.

Next, I also have certain services after calling the API which only authenticated users are supposed to get access to. For this, the Mobile App logs in with a Username and password which is authenticated in the User table of my Database. If it passes, the server generates a User Token and passes it to the Mobile App. The User Token is also saved in the User table against that User. All subsequent requests from the App (which requires user authentication) passes this User Token which is checked in the User table in the Database for User Authentication. If the Mobile App logs out, this User Token is deleted from the User table. I also have provision to add "TimeToExpire" for this User Token which I will implement later.

I would be really grateful if you guys could tell me the following:

- Does the above structure makes sense for App Authentication and User Authentication?
- I am a little lost as to what will happen if I ever need to change the API Key (for whatever reason). Not sure how that will be sent to all the Apps. Google Messaging seems like one possible way to handle that.
- For the App Authentication, does it make sense to keep the API Key in a Memcached object? Since all requests from the Apps are authenticated, I don't want to go to the DB everytime. And pros/cons?
- Along the same lines, does it also make sense to have the User Token in a Memcached object as well? Pros/cons?

Comment: I am following the same pattern you are suggesting in my app and so far I have no issues.

Comment: @IllegalArgument Thanks for the confirmation :) Comforting to know it's working well for you. Have you had issues with changing the API Key and updating the Apps about it?

Comment: I only keep the client id and client secret in my app the api key is not used in my case. the first instantiation of our code will fetch the access token from the web.